# How to dynamically pass a parameter to WHERE clause in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCustomers_PagerSelected]
    @PageIndex INT,
    @PageSize INT = 10,
    @SubCondition nvarchar(max),
    @RecordCount INT OUTPUT
AS  
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Plan_Id] ASC) AS RowNumber,
        [Plan_Id], [User_Id], [Plan_Name], 
        [ImageCount], [PlanPrice],
        '../User/HomePlanImage/' + CONVERT(varchar(5), User_Id ) +'/' + CONVERT(varchar(5), Plan_Id ) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar(5),1) +'.jpg' AS PlanImagePath
    INTO 
        #Results
    FROM 
        [mf_BuildingPlanDetails]
    WHERE 
        IsActive = 1 @SubCondition 

    SELECT 
        @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM 
        #Results

    SELECT * 
    FROM #Results
    WHERE 
        RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1 

    DROP TABLE #Results
```

Comment: The only way to do such a thing is to use dynamic sql. If you can provide some background and explain your goal better, perhaps someone will be able to show you a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Want to pass @SubCondition parameter to where clause in above code

Comment: Yes, that was clear from reading the code. However, as I wrote, this can only be done if you are using dynamic sql, and that opens a door to a world of problems. This is why I suggest you edit your question to include some more background, like what are the values you want to allow in `@SubCondition`.

Comment: in @SubCondition i was passing  'AND column_name IN(column_value) AND column_name IN(column_value,column_value)'

Comment: Is the `column_name` always the same column? if not, you must use dynamic sql.

Comment: column_name will be different every time

Comment: now how to use dynamic sql ??

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should probably do what you want:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCustomers_PagerSelected]
    @PageIndex INT,
    @PageSize INT = 10,
    @SubCondition nvarchar(max),
    @RecordCount INT OUTPUT
AS  
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Sql varchar(max)

    CREATE TABLE #Results
    (
        RowNumber int,
        Plan_Id int, -- Guessing the column data type, change if needed
        User_Id int, -- Guessing the column data type, change if needed
        Plan_Name varchar(200), -- Guessing the column data type and lengthe, change if needed
        ImageCount int, -- Guessing the column data type, change if needed
        PlanPrice money, -- Guessing the column data type, change if needed
        PlanImagePath varchar(300), -- Guessing the column data type and lengthe, change if needed
    )

    SET @Sql = '
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Plan_Id] ASC) AS RowNumber,
        [Plan_Id], 
        [User_Id], 
        [Plan_Name], 
        [ImageCount], 
        [PlanPrice],
        ''../User/HomePlanImage/'' + CONVERT(varchar(5), User_Id ) + 
                                ''/'' + CONVERT(varchar(5), Plan_Id ) + 
                                ''/'' + CONVERT(varchar(5),1) + 
                                ''.jpg'' AS PlanImagePath

    FROM 
        [mf_BuildingPlanDetails]
    WHERE 
        IsActive = 1 ' + @SubCondition 

    INSERT INTO #Results 
    EXEC sp_executeSql @Sql

    SELECT 
        @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM 
        #Results

    SELECT * 
    FROM #Results
    WHERE 
        RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1 

    DROP TABLE #Results
END
```

**However**, Please note that using a query like this is a **security hazard** since it's vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. 
I would strongly recommend a different approach, however I can't advise on that because I don't have enough information.

Comment: "Not working" - how? Do you get an error? Do you get different results then expected?

Comment: After doing some correction its work thanku @Zohar_Peled

Comment: Well, in that case, please either post your solution as an asnwer and accept it, or edit my answer to show the changes you made and accept it, so that other people will know that the problem is solved.